# array.push() does not push element

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to push an element at index 0 of an existing array to a new array with .push(), but it isn't pushed into the new array.

I've tried .push() and .unshift(), none of them worked. I printed out both arrays and element, element is not null and after .push() array2 is empty. 
I've declared array1 and array2 in init() and filled array1 with elements, which are all in the array (Known due to console.log)
array1 contains custom elements which are loaded from my server and added to the array, it is not empty!

```js
array1: SimpleQuestionDTO[] = [];
array2: SimpleQuestionDTO[] = [];

this.questionController.getSimpleQuestionDTOListByIdListUsingGET(this.convertArrayFromNumberToString(this.allQuestionIdsNumber)).subscribe(response => {
   this.array1 = response;
});

vocabLearned(successful: boolean) {
    this.currentArrayLearning();

    if (successful) {
      switch (this.currentArray) {
        case 1:
          let element = this.array1[0];
          this.array2.push(element);
          console.log('Element at index 0: ', element);
        default:
          break;
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result is of course array2 now contains the element of index 0 from array1.

Comment: You have not posted enough code for anyone to be able to help. How exactly do you know that `.push()` is not working?

Comment: @Pointy I printed out array2 with console.log and it was empty

Comment: **Post more code.** What's in `this.array1`? How do you know it's there? The `.push()` function does in fact work, of course.

Comment: where are you setting values for array1 and array2 before this?

Comment: @Pointy I've added some more code and information

Comment: The problem is that the function call you're making is *asynchronous*.  If you did that `.push()` *inside* the callback function, you'd see that it works.

Comment: @Pointy Added a bit more of code :D I'm calling .push() in a whole other function :)

Comment: It doesn't matter. The function with the insanely long name will return immediately, and the callback function will be called later when the operation completes. Asynchronous APIs are a fundamental part of working in JavaScript.